# Is there a function to call the class name in a template<> without typing the name of the class yourself?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction, class-template

I am trying to get the type name of a class. Of course, I could just use `typename(class)` but I need to place it in a template like this

```
ClassA<typeid(class).name()> a = ClassA<typeid(class).name()>(args);
```

This is what I tried:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
   T t; // the class

   A(T t1)
   {
      t = t1;
   }
};

class B // example class
{
public:
   int i;

   B(int i1)
   {
      i = i1;
   }
};

int main()
{
   B b = B(1);
   A<typeid(b).name()>(b) a = A<typeid(b).name()>(b); // my issue
}
```

But it always gives me an error.

```
'A': invalid template argument for 'T', type expected.
```

Is there any way round this (class `A` needs to be able to accept any class in one attribute)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way around this (`class A` needs to be able to accept any class in one attribute)?

What you are looking for is the [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) keyword. You need

```
A<decltype(b)> a = A<decltype(b)>{ b };
// or just
auto a = A<decltype(b)>{ b };
```

However, since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), thanks to [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), which allows you to write just.

```
A a{ b }; // no need of "A<-template-para-list->"
```

---

**Side note**: If you do not initialize the members in the [constructor initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), the passed `T` in `A` must be default constructible. Therefore, I would recommend

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    T t;
public:   

    A(T t1)
        : t{ t1 } // ---> initialize in constructor initializer list
    {}
};
```

[Live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qj3sr4s9z)

Comment: The sidenote is a good point. It also covers the case where T can't be assigned to. (E.g. `T= const B`)